# SharePoint list saves a date with a day before

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2013

I need to save on a date in a sharepoint list using javascript, but in sharepoint saves the date with a previous day

Javascript "18/08/2016" and list sharepoint "17/08/20106"

Comment: Not sure to understand. You said that you use Javascript to add a date to a Sharepoint list? Is that correct? If so, can you add an example of the JavaScript code that you use to add a date in your Sharepoint List ?

Comment: var fechaPa =  "18/08/2016";
var fechaPag = fechaPa.split("/")[1] +"/"+ fechaPa.split("/")[0] +"/"+ fechaPa.split("/")[2];

fechaPago = new Date(fechaPag);

fechaPago = fechaPago.toISOString()

var customerData = {
       __metadata: { "type": "SP.Data.PruebaFechasListItem" },
       Fecha1:fechaPago 
 };
 
 createNewItem(customerData, "NameList");

@SylvainB

Comment: @SylvainB, .I use javascript to save an item in the list of sharepoint. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sharepoint factors in Time Zones, and will alter dates if the originating time zone is different than the server time zone.  Dates without a specified time default to midnight(00:00).  If the server time zone is behind the originating time zone, this will cause the date to roll back a day

Answer (score 0):

I made a test in my Sharepoint 2013 and its seems to work.

Here is my code :

```
<script>
function getItemTypeForListName(listName) {
    return "SP.Data." + listName.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + listName.split(" ").join("").slice(1) + "ListItem";
};

function createNewItem(customerData, listName) {
    var strData = JSON.stringify(customerData);
    var urlListe =  "http://[URL_OF_YOUR_SP_SITE]/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items";
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: urlListe,
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: 'application/json;odata=verbose',
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        },
        processData: false,
        data: strData,
        success: function (data) {
            $('#SaveResult').html('Success');
        },
        error: function (data) {
            $('#SaveResult').html('Error');
        }
    });
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#SaveDateToList').on('click',function(){
        var fechaPa = "18/08/2016"; 
        var fechaPag = fechaPa.split("/")[1] +"/"+ fechaPa.split("/")[0] +"/"+ fechaPa.split("/")[2]; 
        fechaPago = new Date(fechaPag); 
        fechaPago = fechaPago.toISOString() 
        var customerData = { 
            __metadata:{
                type:getItemTypeForListName("TestList")
            }, 
            TestDate:fechaPago 
        }; 
        createNewItem(customerData, "TestList");
    });
});
</script>

<a id="SaveDateToList">Save</a>

<div id="SaveResult"></div>
```

Comment: Have you looked at the time zones?  I've seen too many times that SP changed the date because the originating point was one hour ahead of the actual server, and dates with not time are set to midnight (00:00) so when it converts it to the servers time, it rolls it back an hour or whatever the difference is and that changes the date

Comment: if I see items from the api brings me good information, but if I look at it from the list view does not work.

@DaveV  how I can see the time zones?

Comment: saved in the list with this date (17/08/2016). It does not work on my site. attached screenshot. screencast.com/t/z5pvdjtP

@SylvainB

Comment: @DaveV please put this as answer.